# Handling "NotImplementedError" in GroupBy Mean: Google Colab vs. Jupyter/VSCode Differences and a Universal Solution

Tags: python, visual-studio, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

During a recent data analysis task, I encountered an intriguing issue while attempting to use the `groupby('Group').mean()` operation in pandas. What caught my attention was that while the code executed smoothly in **Google Colab**, the same code triggered a rather perplexing `NotImplementedError` when run in **Jupyter Notebook** or **VSCode**. The error message indicated that `"function is not implemented for this dtype."`

Delving deeper into the issue, I discovered that the root of the problem lies in subtle differences between coding environments and pandas configurations. Specifically, **Google Colab** seemingly allows the `mean()` operation on a DataFrame with non-numeric columns, resulting in a seamless execution. In contrast, **Jupyter Notebook** and **VSCode** raise a `NotImplementedError` under similar circumstances.

To establish a consistent approach across various coding environments, I managed to successfully execute the `groupby('Group').mean()` operation across all platforms. Here's the code snippet that circumvents the `NotImplementedError` and ensures reliable execution.
Here's the code snippet that bypasses the error:

```
import pandas as pd

# Default numeric columns for mean calculation
numeric_columns = ['Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3', 'Column4', 'Column5']

# Group by 'Group' column and calculate mean for numeric columns
grouped_mean = clean_df.groupby('Group')[numeric_columns].mean()

# Print the result
print(grouped_mean)
```

**Navigating the Solution:**

1. I identified numeric columns using `select_dtypes(include=[np.number])`.
2. Exclusively applied the `groupby('Group').mean()` operation to numeric columns.
3. By adopting this strategy, only numeric columns contribute to the mean calculation, effectively mitigating the `NotImplementedError`.

Implementing this strategy empowers you to confidently leverage `groupby('Group').mean()` operations on DataFrames in various coding environments. This solution bridges the gap between **Google Colab's** behavior and that of **Jupyter Notebook/VSCode**, ensuring your code's portability and reliability. I hope my experience and solution prove beneficial to others navigating similar challenges.

I hope that sharing my experience and solution proves beneficial to fellow data enthusiasts and analysts who may encounter a similar challenge.

(Note: Replace '`clean_df`' with your actual DataFrame and adjust column names as needed.)